# How to catch mouse event click on jframe

Tags: java, resize, jframe

I am trying to catch the event when mouse is pressed on any corner of frame. 
I have already tried every mouse listener, however it doesn't work. Everything works fine when I'm clicking on the pane, but every click on frame (no matter if it's a frame or a menu bar) is ignored.

I know when dragging the frame is finished. Have you got any idea how to solve it?

Component resized doesn't not work for me, because I have to resize it after dragging is finished (mouse button released).

Comment: Could you please provide also the code you tried to solve the problem with, as well as a sample screenshot?

Comment: Why do you have to resize anything? It all seems very hacky. There are layout managers to handle stuff for that. If you don't want the user to resize a JFrame then `jframe.setResizable(false);`. What are you goals here?

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here. Also explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It is required to pass the academic course. I have to make scalable game but when components resizes constantly becouse of casting to int componensts changes their locations.  need to know when resizing is finished to block resizing constantly. I cannot post code, becouse there are a lot of classes etc.

Comment: You surely *can* post code and you should. If you read the link, you will see that you need to make a simple example. Add 1 of your components and show how resizing the frame causes unintended behavior. I think your approach is just wrong, the frame decorations can be platform specific.

Comment: `I have to make scalable game but when components resizes constantly becouse of casting to int componensts changes their locations. need to know when resizing is finished to block resizing constantly.` - that is the job of the layout manager to dynamically set the size/location of components. `I cannot post code, becouse there are a lot of classes` - of course you can. We did not ask for your application. We asked for code that demonstrates the problem. So create a simple example that demonstrates the concept. We don't need all the logic of the game.

Comment: *Everything works fine when I'm clicking on the pane, but every click on frame (no matter if it's a frame or a menu bar) is ignored.*  Yes.  That's how Java Swing was designed.  Dragging and resizing the JFrame is done with operating system functions.